# Is it Possible to play Dead Rising 3 Indefinitely?

Tags: dead-rising-3

While playing Dead Rising 3, you find out that:

> You have to get out of the main town before the US Military bombs it due to zombies.  You have ~5 days to [continue the story line and] get out.

Is it possible to keep feeding my desire to kill zombies without worrying about the event to come?

I also ask this because I want to see all tragic endings and obtain all collectibles around the map (which is very time consuming).

I am playing on Normal Difficulty - which the game told me when I selected this difficulty that it will allow me more time to collect items.

Comment: reason I could never enjoy the Dead Rising series. everything was timed, could never just enjoy the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your character level, collectibles and pp trials carry through into other normal mode playthroughs and even nightmare mode, so in theory you can essentially play forever.

I have confirmed this since I finished normal mode, picking up all collectibles and then started a new game in nightmare mode.  I had carried over all my level, attribute points, books and collectibles (including combos, blueprints etc.)

The only thing that doesn't carry over is any posse members you may have rescued, you'll need to rescue them again in new playthroughs.

Comment: This also holds true for the first two (or three, if you count the alternate #2)

Answer (score 1):

there is a simple way of avoiding this, just go to chapter 8 and don't go to the roof top to see the spaceship, this gives you infinite time as the clock has stopped plus a posse member Chuck.